# Get midpoints of equal-width bins

Tags: r

I'd like to associate each element of a numeric vector with the midpoint of its bin, when binning into `k` equal-width bins.

`ggplot2::cut_interval` can produce equal-width bins, and `Hmisc::cut2` can provide the midpoint, but I don't see a way to do both together.

Minimal reproducible example:

```
v <- c(1, 2, 7, 9)

# cut_interval gives equal-width bins, but no midpoints.
ggplot2::cut_interval(v, 2)
# [1] [1,5] [1,5] (5,9] (5,9]
# Levels: [1,5] (5,9]

# cut2 doesn't give equal-width bins.
Hmisc::cut2(v, g=2)
# [1] [1,7) [1,7) [7,9] [7,9]
# Levels: [1,7) [7,9]

# But it returns the midpoint.
Hmisc::cut2(v, g=2, levels.mean=T)
# [1] 1.5 1.5 8.0 8.0
# Levels: 1.5 8.0

# Which can be extracted as a numeric.
as.numeric(as.character(Hmisc::cut2(v, g=2, levels.mean=T)))
# [1] 1.5 1.5 8.0 8.0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want automatically selected bins, just use `hist()`. It provides several algorithms for how the binwidths are selected:

```
set.seed(47)
h1 = hist(rnorm(100))
h1$breaks
# [1] -2.5 -2.0 -1.5 -1.0 -0.5  0.0  0.5  1.0  1.5  2.0  2.5
h1$mids
# [1] -2.25 -1.75 -1.25 -0.75 -0.25  0.25  0.75  1.25  1.75  2.25
```

If you want to add the binning to your data, use `cut` with the breaks provided by `hist`. To add just the midpoints, you can do `cut(my_data, breaks = h1$breaks, labels = h1$mids)`.

On your data:

```
v <- c(1, 2, 7, 9)
h2 = hist(v)
h2$breaks
# [1]  0  2  4  6  8 10
h2$mids
# [1] 1 3 5 7 9
```

The `hist` object also has other useful info, the `count`, the `density`. You can set `plot = FALSE` if you don't want the plot to pop up, and see `?hist` for many other options.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the upper and lower bounds from each `cut_interval` bin:

```
EqualWidthBinMidpoint <- function(x, k) {
  # Returns midpoints of equal-width bins.
  #
  # Args:
  #   x: Vector to bin.
  #   k: Number of bins.
  #
  # Returns:
  #   Numeric vector with midpoint of each element of x's bin.
  ci <- as.character(ggplot2::cut_interval(x, k))
  ci2 <- substr(as.character(ci), 2, nchar(as.character(ci)) - 1)
  lb <- sapply(ci2, function(x) strsplit(x, ",")[[1]][1])
  ub <- sapply(ci2, function(x) strsplit(x, ",")[[1]][2])
  return((as.numeric(lb) + as.numeric(ub)) / 2)
}

EqualWidthBinMidpoint(v, 2)
# [1] 3 3 7 7
```